# Permitted background task scheduler identifiers missing Mapbox

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, mapbox, ios13

Today I wanted to submit my application builded on Mapbox Navigation SDK and all its dependencies. Sadly enough App Store Connect denies my upload every time because of the following error:

[image: Image error App Store Connect]
To make the SDK work, the documents said to enable the following background modes:

- App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay
- App registers for location updates
- App downloads content in response to push notifications

From now on in IOS13 Apple expects you to provide the identifiers for those modes. Only problem, I can't find them anywhere.

Can someone help me with this?

***Steps to reproduce***

- Implement Mapbox SDK, Directions SDK, Navigation SDK, ...
- Enable the background modes: App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay, App registers for location updates, App downloads content in response to push notifications
- Try to archive and publish the app to App Store Connect

***Expected behavior***

Completed the identifiers for the backgroundtask in info.plist that the app can archive and build to App Store Connect without any problem

**Actual behavior**

Localy the app runs without it, but when you want to upload it to App Store Connect, it requests those identifiers. Without those identifiers in info.plist it won't upload.

***Configuration***

** Mapbox SDK versions: pod 'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.38.0' **

** iOS/macOS versions: iOS 13.1.3 (17A878) **

** Device/simulator models: Iphone XS Max iOS 13.1.3 (17A878) **

** Xcode version: Version 11.0 (11A420a) **

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you’re confusing two things. You seem to have checked the new iOS 13 background mode Background Processing by mistake. Uncheck it. It is not any of the modes you said you needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed it were thos who made it fail to upload. Can you explain in which case you would use those new BG modes from IOS13

Comment: Do not ever check any modes or add any capabilities that you do not need.

Answer (score 13):

**for Those who are searching Solution add These Lines in info.plist**

```
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    </array>
```